# Raspberry Pi 3 has only 128MB memory available at OS level

Tags: raspberry-pi-os, performance

I don't know why but my Raspbian installation say me that the Total RAM is 128MB instead of near to 1024MB.

[image]

|  | total | used | free | shared |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Mem:** | 116672 kB | 54912 kB | 26292 kB | 192 kB |
| **Swap:** | 102396 kb | 98160 kB | 4236 kB |  |

Instead, the Total RAM with another Raspbian installation (with same Raspberry PI) I obtain this:

[image]

|  | total | used | free | shared |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Mem:** | 948304 kB | 124296 kB | 580388 kB | 14052 kB |
| **Swap:** | 102396 kb | 0 kB | 102396 kB |  |

Can someone help me please?

Note: the Raspberry PI is 3 B+.
The SD card is built 2 years ago. In last days the computer do not works properly. So I understand that it was a power supply issue. Then now I use a new power supply, but the boot is very very slow. The reason (my opinion) is because the total RAM is 128MB only.
Something say to operating system that this is all RAM available.

Comment: @Milliways is now better?

Comment: Edit in a cut n' paste (not screenshot) of the output from `cat /proc/meminfo`.

Comment: What have you done to the broken install? Any reason you can't just reflash?

Comment: @CoderMike I haven't a broken installation. The SD is built 2 years ago. Today it do not works after issues of power supply. Replaced it, now I look that the boot is very slow. Because (I think) the ram is only 128MB.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you allocated almost all of your memory to the GPU.
If you run raspi-config, (Performance Options -> GPU Memory) you can change the GPU memory to a lower number and then the remaining memory is available for general use again.

Comment: I try this but it do not solve. And if I set 32 MB, the Raspberry do not power-on: red led is on, green led is off.